# Dog won't go outside at night to pee

Tags: dogs, toilet-training

I wake up every morning to find that my 9 month old Dachshund has pee'd somewhere in the house, lately just next to the back door *just in front of his dog door that he very well knows how to use*.

When we are out for the day, he goes outside to toilet 9 days out of 10. When we are home, he seems sometimes reluctant to go out on his own to do his business.

What can I do to get him to understand that it is good to go outside even when it is night time?

Comment: He has no trouble using the dog door during the day? What kind of lighting do you have outside at night?

Comment: Nope, he's in and out through the dog door all day. He even goes out when it is dark (while we are still up) occasionally. We have some solar powered garden lights outside, and it is rarely fully dark outside, due to city lights, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would start limiting his space at night to a small easily cleanable area. Use a cleaner designed to eliminate pet waste as the smell can encourage them to go there again.

I have a crate that I put my dog in at night while I'm asleep, because as well housebroken as she is, she'll still try to go in the house sometimes. This is especially likely if it's cold out and she doesn't want to go out. However, I make it a point to go out with her at night and walk her around. I want to see her go potty even before putting her to bed. I'll also drag her out of bed in the morning whether she wants to go or not. She usually does. I sometimes have to walk her around the yard for 10-15 minutes before she goes. She'll try to sit and stare at me, but if I walk off and call her to me she'll walk over. Eventually, she'll veer off and pee, then I give her a 'Good Girl' and we go straight in. I also made it a point to say, 'Go Potty' while she's peeing. Then if she doesn't want to go, I say it and hope it's formed an association in her head.

Things that make it more likely for a dog to want to go to he bathroom are: just waking up, playing, eating, going for a walk. If you try to do these things before taking her to potty, she'll be much more likely to go.

Comment: I used a cleaner as recommended on the places he most often went to the toilet, and also established a routine, same time, same place, morning and night. Still occasionally come home to a mess, but this is becoming rarer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried taking him outside with you to do his business? Do you have a command for going?

If you haven't got a command, he will learn one quickly - just give him the command just before he goes, every time he goes when you're with him. At night before you retire, take him out to his usual spot (if he has one; if he doesn't, take him to the same spot each time, so he'll want to cover the scent again) and give him the command. Placing him in a crate for the night will discourage him from urinating in his space - he'll hold it till morning. When he's been accident-free for a few weeks, you can let him out again at night.

Comment: Hi, it's been some time since I've last seen you talking in Litter Box chat, could you please let me know whether you are OK? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As he does not seem to have a problem going outside during the day, but is hesitant to go out at night.  It reasonable to assume he does not want to go out at night, he may be afraid and his fear is not unfounded.

Dachshund are repetitively [small dogs weighting between 8 lb (3.6 kg) & 32 lb (15 kg)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dachshund#Size).  There are a several [birds of prey in Australia](http://beautyofbirds.com/australianbirdsofprey.html), there may also be other predators who are about in the night time.  Some authorities recommend [never letting a pet under 15 lb (7 kg) outside alone.](http://hawksaloft.org/hawks-aloft-inc-2/frequently-asked-questions/) we have a related post https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6785

Maybe it is NOT "good to go outside even when it is night time", and he knows it.

Comment: The raptors will only be out during the day, so it's pretty unlikely that they're anything to worry about at night. Owls also prefer to swallow prey whole (they're beaks aren't exactly made for cutting meat), so they're also not much worry. I would be more concerned about other mammals.

Comment: How would the dog know not to go outside during night? Unless the dog had some kind of a incident with going through the doggy door at night. If something happened to the dog at night, I don't even think they are able to associate night time and the bad thing that happened

Comment: [Ivan Pavlov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivan_Pavlov) showed that dogs are able to associate to things much more subtle than night or day.